# Submitting form data to a popup window for processing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, window.open

As so many posts start: This might be a duplicate, but...

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Have an HTML page within my site that contains a FORM element with various input, etc. elements inside, e.g.:

```html
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" id="text1" size=10><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="This text is hidden">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="Y"> Include stuff?<br>
    Job Title: <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">President</option>
    <option value="2">Chief Cook</option>
    <option value="3">Bottle Washer</option>
    </select>
    <button name="button1" id="button1" onclick="doThisScript()">Submit Stuff</button>
    </form>
```

2. I want the "doThisScript" function to open a new popup window with coded parameters, directed to a url on our site, and pass the form's values to that url, something like:

```js
    function doThisScript() {
    var form1=document.getElementById('form1');
    form1.onsubmit=function() {
    var w=window.open('resultsprogram.asp','resultswin','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300');
    this.target = 'resultswin';
    form1.submit();
    }
    }
```

This code (based on the closest Q/A here I could find) *transfers* the form from the "base" page to the popup window. But what I'm trying to do, I guess, is submit the form back to the server but have the results come back to that popup window instead of either the base page or a new tab/standard browser window.

Is that even possible? I assumed there had to be a way to create the popupwin with a URL, pass that page the current form values, and tell that popupwin to itself submit the form so that it, not the base page, gets the results. Doable?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `window.open()` will invoke the server script, but it won't send the form parameters to it.

You need to change the form's action to be the server script:

```
function doThisScript() {
    var form1=document.getElementById('form1');
    form1.action = 'resultprogram.asp';
    form1.target = 'resultswin';
    }
}
```

You don't need to call `submit()` explicitly, since that's the default action of clicking on the submit button.

Comment: Doh. I'd actually included the URL in a previous attempt at the script, but had taken it out to test setting the URL programmatically - and forgot to put it back in once I'd solved the separate issue I was tinkering with. Thank you very much - I'd been staring at that for hours trying to figure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You can also just use `<form action="resultprogram.asp" target="resultswin">` in the HTML

Comment: The problem with that approach is that most browsers use "target=" to open a new tab or a new full browser window (at least in my experience). The problem we run into with our website with some of our, ahem, less sophisticated users is that they end up with ten open tabs from our site, and then can't figure out why "Back" doesn't do anything, and they end up closing out the browser in frustration. The window.open window makes it clear this is a "results" box.